# Do I need transit visa in Bangkok for a 12 hour 20 minute layover?

Tags: visas, bangkok

I'd like to know if I need a Transit visa for a 12 hour 20 minute layover in Suvarnabhumi Intl, Thailand before my onward flight.
My itinerary is as follows:

Chennai, to Bangkok (arriving at 06.25), 
a 12 hour and 20 minute layover (departing at 6.45pm), then
Bangkok to Auckland, NZ.

Comment: check on the embassy website. They def have that information there

Comment: For an Indian passport I presume?

Answer (score 5):

So, presuming you are an Indian citizen since you are leaving from India, you will need a visa. Thailand offers 12 hours of Visa free transit time, whereas your layover is 12 hours and 20 minutes.

> Passengers transiting through Bangkok (BKK) with a confirmed onward
>   ticket for a flight to a third country within 12 hours. They must stay
>   in the international transit area of the airport and have documents
>   required for the next destination. ([source](https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b))

Note that you will also need a visa for New Zealand.